# Condition to set a flag in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have Makefile where flag is set for IPv6 compilation.

```
IPV6 = 1

ifeq ($(IPV6), 1)
```

Then ipv6 targets are include for compilations.

Requirement: 
    I want to enable this flag based on feature, and this feature is part of the CFLAG.

```
ifdef IPV6_FEATURE
  IPV6=1
else
  IPV6=0
endif
```

But since IPV6_FEATURE is not available in Makefile as it is a global include, it will always going to else.

Please let me know if any alternatives for this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, in the cases where `IPV6_FEATURE` is defined, it gets included after the section where you are testing it.  This does not work, since make evaluates conditionals when it reads the makefile.

The solution is to not use an `ifdef` to set `IPV6`, and use a conditional function instead.

```
IPV6 = $(if $(IPV6_FEATURE), 1, 0)
```

This will set `IPV6=1` if `IPV6_FEATURE` is defined to some non-empty value.

You may also need to change how you are using `$(IPV6)`, so that you don't have an `ifeq` conditional.